# Livedata class inner members in databinding

Tags: android, mvvm, android-databinding, android-architecture-components, android-livedata

if I have a class

```
data class item(val address: String = ""
                )
```

its declared in my viewmodel
    var varLive: MutableLiveData = MutableLiveData()

and later on I post it from my viewmodel
        varLive.postValue(scootersList[marker])

in my xml I have

```
    <TextView
    ... 
    android:text="@{vModel.varLive.address}"
/>
```

And I can't access  item.address and get a databinding error.
I can check if the varLive is null and tht is it
Do I really have to declare each of the livedata class fields as a live data? If I have a class holding 100 members?

Comment: If I have a class holding 100 members? ==> You don't display the 100 stuff on the UI generally. We need to create LiveData object for the stuff we really need to show in UI.

Comment: I am, but why can't I access vModel.varLive.address? via viewbinding?

Answer (score 0):

for some stupid reason you have to specify a getter method in your viewmodel, so databinding can pick it up. like so:

```
fun getvarLive() = varLive
```

Kotlin actially does that for you. But databinding won't bind Kotlin getters. Seriosly annoying